# I have to rebuild my DLL twice when I swap from x64 to x86 and vice versa

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I change my configuration to build x64 or x86 and I click **rebuild** I get this output:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1313,5): error MSB3097: File "D:\My Programs\2017\MSAToolsLibrary\MSAToolsLibrary\bin\x86\Release\MSAToolsLibrary.dll" is not a valid assembly.

I have to right-click the project again and choose rebuild a second time and it is fine.

It is not a big issue. But why does it happen? Can it be avoided?

Comment: Does it happen with multiple project(s) or just one? With a brand new project?

Comment: Just created a new C# DLL project that also registers for COM interop and it does exactly the same thing. You always have to build twice after switching.

Comment: Expectation is that Rebuild will do a Clean first and thus delete any existing DLL in the build output directory.  You are using a beta release, report bugs to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant Sure. I didn't know if this was a bug ir if it was standard behaviour in Visual Studio.